Always etting error 404 when trying to enter traefik dashboard
I'm trying to run traefic on my docker, I instaled it, everything work I even have let's encrypt staging certs, but when I'm trying to login to dashboard I'm geting 404 error page not found
i'm gona use mydomain.com as placeholder for my actuall domain on cloudflare, lab. is CNAME for DynamicDNS for my IP, soo lab.mydomain.com subdomain is what I'm using for all my docker containers etc. with ports at the end.
This is my docker-compose.yml for traefik
version: "3.8"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      # - 443:443/tcp 
      # - 443:443/udp 
    environment:
      CF_DNS_API_TOKEN_FILE: /run/secrets/cf_api_token # note using _FILE for docker secrets
      # CF_DNS_API_TOKEN: ${CF_DNS_API_TOKEN} # if using .env
      TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_CREDENTIALS: ${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_CREDENTIALS}
    secrets:
      - cf_api_token
    env_file: .env # use .env
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
      # - ./data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.lab.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD_CREDENTIALS}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.lab.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=lab.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.lab.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

secrets:
  cf_api_token:
    file: ./cf_api_token.txt

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

And this is traefik.yml
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  # file:
  #   filename: /config.yml
certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: mail@mydomain.com
      storage: acme.json
      # caServer: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # prod (default)
      caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # staging
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        #disablePropagationCheck: true # uncomment this if you have issues pulling certificates through cloudflare, By setting this flag to true disables the need to wait for the propagation of the TXT record to all authoritative name servers.
        #delayBeforeCheck: 60s # uncomment along with disablePropagationCheck if needed to ensure the TXT record is ready before verification is attempted 
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"

What can be wrong with it?
I tryed using ports at the end of lab.mydomain.com but it didint work

Enable and check Traefik debug logs and Traefik access log in JSON format.
Make sure to use the right path when accessing, from the doc:

The dashboard is available at the same location as the API but on the path /dashboard/ by default.
The trailing slash / in /dashboard/ is mandatory

